# PySpark Create Relationship between DataFrame Columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement some logic to get a relationship between ID and Link based on the logic below.

**Logic** -

- if id 1 has link with 2 and 2 has link with 3, then relation is 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2
- Similarly if 1 with 4, 4 with 7 and 7 with 5 then relation is 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 7, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 4, 5 -> 7

**Input DataFrame** -

```
+---+----+
| id|link|
+---+----+
|  1|   2|
|  3|   1|
|  4|   2|
|  6|   5|
|  9|   7|
|  9|  10|
+---+----+
```

I am trying to achieve below output-

```
+---+----+
| Id|Link|
+---+----+
|  1|   2|
|  1|   3|
|  1|   4|
|  2|   1|
|  2|   3|
|  2|   4|
|  3|   1|
|  3|   2|
|  3|   4|
|  4|   1|
|  4|   2|
|  4|   3|
|  5|   6|
|  6|   5|
|  7|   9|
|  7|  10|
|  9|   7|
|  9|  10|
| 10|   7|
| 10|   9|
+---+----+
```

I have tried many way, but it's not at all working. I have tried following codes as well

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (6, 5), (9, 7), (9, 10)], ["id", "link"])
ids = df.select("Id").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
links = df.select("Link").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
combinations = [(id, link) for id in ids for link in links]
df_combinations = spark.createDataFrame(combinations, ["Id", "Link"])
result = df_combinations.join(df, ["Id", "Link"], "left_anti").union(df).dropDuplicates()
result = result.sort(asc("Id"), asc("Link"))
```

and

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (6, 5), (9, 7), (9, 10)], ["id", "link"])

combinations = df.alias("a").crossJoin(df.alias("b")) \
    .filter(F.col("a.id") != F.col("b.id"))\
    .select(col("a.id").alias("a_id"), col("b.id").alias("b_id"), col("a.link").alias("a_link"), col("b.link").alias("b_link"))

window = Window.partitionBy("a_id").orderBy("a_id", "b_link")
paths = combinations.groupBy("a_id", "b_link") \
    .agg(F.first("b_id").over(window).alias("id")) \
    .groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_list("b_link").alias("links"))

result = paths.select("id", F.explode("links").alias("link"))
result = result.union(df.selectExpr("id as id_", "link as link_"))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a general approach but you can use the `graphframes` package. You might struggle to set it up but one can use it, the result is simple.

```
import os
sc.addPyFile(os.path.expanduser('graphframes-0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar'))

from graphframes import *

e = df.select('id', 'link').toDF('src', 'dst')
v = e.select('src').toDF('id') \
  .union(e.select('dst')) \
  .distinct()

g = GraphFrame(v, e)

sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/graphframes")
df = g.connectedComponents()

df.join(df.withColumnRenamed('id', 'link'), ['component'], 'inner') \
  .drop('component') \
  .filter('id != link') \
  .show()

+---+----+
| id|link|
+---+----+
|  7|  10|
|  7|   9|
|  3|   2|
|  3|   4|
|  3|   1|
|  5|   6|
|  6|   5|
|  9|  10|
|  9|   7|
|  1|   2|
|  1|   4|
|  1|   3|
| 10|   9|
| 10|   7|
|  4|   2|
|  4|   1|
|  4|   3|
|  2|   4|
|  2|   1|
|  2|   3|
+---+----+
```

`connectedComponents` method returns the component id for each vertex, that is unique for each vertex group (that is connected by edge and seperated if there is no edge to the other component). So you can do the cartesian product for each component without the vertex itself.

**Added answer**

Inspired from the above approach, I looked up and found the `networkx` package.

```
import networkx as nx

df = df.toPandas()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'id', 'link')
components = [[list(c)] for c in nx.connected_components(G)]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(components, ['array']) \
  .withColumn('component', f.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
  .select('component', f.explode('array').alias('id'))

df2.join(df2.withColumnRenamed('id', 'link'), ['component'], 'inner') \
  .drop('component') \
  .filter('id != link') \
  .show()

+---+----+
| id|link|
+---+----+
|  1|   2|
|  1|   3|
|  1|   4|
|  2|   1|
|  2|   3|
|  2|   4|
|  3|   1|
|  3|   2|
|  3|   4|
|  4|   1|
|  4|   2|
|  4|   3|
|  5|   6|
|  6|   5|
|  9|  10|
|  9|   7|
| 10|   9|
| 10|   7|
|  7|   9|
|  7|  10|
+---+----+
```

Comment: you are right. Strugling to setup the library. Added the jar. But getting compilation error on Pycharm for this line of code "from graphframes import *".

Comment: Do you know any process to setup the python library from the Jar on Pycharm. At the moment I am running the entire project on Pycharm. Once it's successfully tested on Local Pycharm, I will run it on EMR